# How to 'Test BACC "Thumper" Solid Fuel Booster in flight over Kerbin'?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

After endless tries, how can it be achieved?

Req: 5Km~14Km, 100~800 m/sec

I created a craft with the device, achieved all test conditions (all is green), still I don't get the achievement. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fulfill an engine test contract, you need to get to the conditions *and then* activate the stage the part is on. That means you need to build a two-stage rocket. The first stage to get the part into the test conditions and the second stage with just the BACC booster which you activate when all conditions are green.

Comment: For some parts (usually parts you can't stage), there can also be a "Run test" entry in the right-click menu of the part.

Comment: A tip for OPs particular contract - since SRBs are heavy you could adjust the amount of Solid Fuel in it to, say, 5% and thus have less mass that you need to bring up to 5Km altitude

Comment: Yep, a rocket composed of one Hammer to get to the desired altitude, one BACC with 5% fuel, and a probe core will suffice (add some parachutes if you want to recover), just make sure to fire the BACC when conditions are met. You may even attach the BACC upside-down, so that it halts your upwards travel for that.

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta BAHAHAHA! Why did it never occur to me to reduce the fuel in the booster? I pulled all of the monopropellant out of the capsule, but I didn't think to pull fuel from the booster. XD Thanks to you, I finally pulled it off. :D I should mention that I was aiming for 160 km, so getting it up there was a little trickier.